# How to install Django on Hostgator?

Tags: django, hosting

I read on *Hostgator* that it is possible to install **Django** on their hosting service, I already contacted the live support and replied that they cannot help with that.

Has somebody already done it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Django on HostGator shared is possible.  It is just a little tricky as Django dropped support for FastCGI.

- Use HostGator's own instructions for setting up Django.
  http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi#shared-reseller
- But then before it will run you need to patch support for FastCGI back into Django.

  - Luckily Django removed FastCGI all in one commit:
    https://github.com/django/django/commit/41f0d3d3bc8b0a6831530e1176c6415f9ba45b0b.patch
  - This patch needs to be reversed and ported to point to the release you have. 
    This kind of requires checking out the django source project and playing with git.
  - Don't worry about deconflicting the docs and tests subfolders as these need to be left out of the re-FastCGI-ification patch anyway.
  - Once armed with the patch file for the version of Django installed in HostGator, use git apply to re-inject FastCGI support into the Django code located in your virtual environment
    `./mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django`
  - At the end is the patch file I ended up with for Django version 1.10.1.
- Use PyMySQL instead of the standard mysql library.  PyMySQL is a pure python mysql client needed as Host Gator doesn't provide gcc.

  - Install the library: `pip install PyMySQL`
  - Monkey patch it in in manage.py and index.fcgi by prepending the following at the beginning of both files just after the #! python line:

```
#monkey patch importing pymysql
try:
    import pymysql
    pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
except ImportError:
    pass
```

```
#Re-fast-cgi-ification-patch
From 51278286d278568dfe89263cad624204c01fa065 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: Joshua 
Date: Tue, 6 Sep 2016 18:19:20 -0400
Subject: django folder only
```

Revert "Removed FastCGI support per deprecation timeline; refs #20766."

This reverts commit 41f0d3d3bc8b0a6831530e1176c6415f9ba45b0b.

# Conflicts:
#   django/core/management/__init__.py
#   docs/howto/deployment/wsgi/index.txt
#   docs/man/django-admin.1
#   docs/ref/django-admin.txt
#   tests/.coveragerc

# Conflicts:
#   docs/man/django-admin.1
#   docs/ref/django-admin.txt

diff --git a/django/conf/global_settings.py b/django/conf/global_settings.py
index 576ff6b..8d1461f 100644
--- a/django/conf/global_settings.py
+++ b/django/conf/global_settings.py
@@ -415,8 +415,8 @@ X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
 USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
 USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = False

-# The Python dotted path to the WSGI application that Django's internal server
-# (runserver) will use. If `None`, the return value of
+# The Python dotted path to the WSGI application that Django's internal servers
+# (runserver, runfcgi) will use. If `None`, the return value of
 # 'django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application' is used, thus preserving the same
 # behavior as previous versions of Django. Otherwise this should point to an
 # actual WSGI application object.
diff --git a/django/core/management/__init__.py b/django/core/management/__init__.py
index 739dc25..2aa84d7 100644
--- a/django/core/management/__init__.py
+++ b/django/core/management/__init__.py
@@ -251,8 +251,13 @@ class ManagementUtility(object):
         # special case: the 'help' subcommand has no options
         elif cwords[0] in subcommands and cwords[0] != 'help':
             subcommand_cls = self.fetch_command(cwords[0])
+            # special case: 'runfcgi' stores additional options as
+            # 'key=value' pairs
+            if cwords[0] == 'runfcgi':
+                from django.core.servers.fastcgi import FASTCGI_OPTIONS
+                options.extend((k, 1) for k in FASTCGI_OPTIONS)
             # special case: add the names of installed apps to options
-            if cwords[0] in ('dumpdata', 'sqlmigrate', 'sqlsequencereset', 'test'):
+            elif cwords[0] in ('dumpdata', 'sqlmigrate', 'sqlsequencereset', 'test'):
                 try:
                     app_configs = apps.get_app_configs()
                     # Get the last part of the dotted path as the app name.
diff --git a/django/core/management/commands/runfcgi.py b/django/core/management/commands/runfcgi.py
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..98de800
--- /dev/null
+++ b/django/core/management/commands/runfcgi.py
@@ -0,0 +1,32 @@
+import argparse
+import warnings
+
+from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
+from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango19Warning
+
+
+class Command(BaseCommand):
+    help = "Runs this project as a FastCGI application. Requires flup."
+
+    def add_arguments(self, parser):
+        parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER,
+            help='Various KEY=val options.')
+
+    def handle(self, *args, **options):
+        warnings.warn(
+            "FastCGI support has been deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.",
+            RemovedInDjango19Warning)
+
+        from django.conf import settings
+        from django.utils import translation
+        # Activate the current language, because it won't get activated later.
+        try:
+            translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
+        except AttributeError:
+            pass
+        from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
+        runfastcgi(args)
+
+    def usage(self, subcommand):
+        from django.core.servers.fastcgi import FASTCGI_HELP
+        return FASTCGI_HELP
diff --git a/django/core/servers/basehttp.py b/django/core/servers/basehttp.py
index 60fc09a..5560438 100644
--- a/django/core/servers/basehttp.py
+++ b/django/core/servers/basehttp.py
@@ -34,11 +34,13 @@ def get_internal_wsgi_application():
     this will be the ``application`` object in ``projectname/wsgi.py``.

     This function, and the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting itself, are only useful
-    for Django's internal server (runserver); external WSGI servers should just
-    be configured to point to the correct application object directly.
+    for Django's internal servers (runserver, runfcgi); external WSGI servers
+    should just be configured to point to the correct application object
+    directly.

     If settings.WSGI_APPLICATION is not set (is ``None``), we just return
     whatever ``django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application`` returns.
+
     """
     from django.conf import settings
     app_path = getattr(settings, 'WSGI_APPLICATION')
diff --git a/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py b/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..b44473b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/django/core/servers/fastcgi.py
@@ -0,0 +1,187 @@
+"""
+FastCGI (or SCGI, or AJP1.3 ...) server that implements the WSGI protocol.
+
+Uses the flup python package: http://www.saddi.com/software/flup/
+
+This is an adaptation of the flup package to add FastCGI server support
+to run Django apps from Web servers that support the FastCGI protocol.
+This module can be run standalone or from the django-admin / manage.py
+scripts using the "runfcgi" directive.
+
+Run with the extra option "help" for a list of additional options you can
+pass to this server.
+"""
+
+import importlib
+import os
+import sys
+
+__version__ = "0.1"
+__all__ = ["runfastcgi"]
+
+FASTCGI_OPTIONS = {
+    'protocol': 'fcgi',
+    'host': None,
+    'port': None,
+    'socket': None,
+    'method': 'fork',
+    'daemonize': None,
+    'workdir': '/',
+    'pidfile': None,
+    'maxspare': 5,
+    'minspare': 2,
+    'maxchildren': 50,
+    'maxrequests': 0,
+    'debug': None,
+    'outlog': None,
+    'errlog': None,
+    'umask': None,
+}
+
+FASTCGI_HELP = r"""
+  Run this project as a fastcgi (or some other protocol supported
+  by flup) application. To do this, the flup package from
+  http://www.saddi.com/software/flup/ is required.
+
+   runfcgi [options] [fcgi settings]
+
+Optional Fcgi settings: (setting=value)
+  protocol=PROTOCOL    fcgi, scgi, ajp, ... (default %(protocol)s)
+  host=HOSTNAME        hostname to listen on.
+  port=PORTNUM         port to listen on.
+  socket=FILE          UNIX socket to listen on.
+  method=IMPL          prefork or threaded (default %(method)s).
+  maxrequests=NUMBER   number of requests a child handles before it is
+                       killed and a new child is forked (0 = no limit).
+  maxspare=NUMBER      max number of spare processes / threads (default %(maxspare)s).
+  minspare=NUMBER      min number of spare processes / threads (default %(minspare)s).
+  maxchildren=NUMBER   hard limit number of processes / threads (default %(maxchildren)s).
+  daemonize=BOOL       whether to detach from terminal.
+  pidfile=FILE         write the spawned process-id to this file.
+  workdir=DIRECTORY    change to this directory when daemonizing (default %(workdir)s).
+  debug=BOOL           set to true to enable flup tracebacks.
+  outlog=FILE          write stdout to this file.
+  errlog=FILE          write stderr to this file.
+  umask=UMASK          umask to use when daemonizing, in octal notation (default 022).
+
+Examples:
+  Run a "standard" fastcgi process on a file-descriptor
+  (for Web servers which spawn your processes for you)
+    $ manage.py runfcgi method=threaded
+
+  Run a scgi server on a TCP host/port
+    $ manage.py runfcgi protocol=scgi method=prefork host=127.0.0.1 port=8025
+
+  Run a fastcgi server on a UNIX domain socket (posix platforms only)
+    $ manage.py runfcgi method=prefork socket=/tmp/fcgi.sock
+
+  Run a fastCGI as a daemon and write the spawned PID in a file
+    $ manage.py runfcgi socket=/tmp/fcgi.sock method=prefork \
+        daemonize=true pidfile=/var/run/django-fcgi.pid
+
+""" % FASTCGI_OPTIONS
+
+
+def fastcgi_help(message=None):
+    print(FASTCGI_HELP)
+    if message:
+        print(message)
+    return False
+
+
+def runfastcgi(argset=[], **kwargs):
+    options = FASTCGI_OPTIONS.copy()
+    options.update(kwargs)
+    for x in argset:
+        if "=" in x:
+            k, v = x.split('=', 1)
+        else:
+            k, v = x, True
+        options[k.lower()] = v
+
+    if "help" in options:
+        return fastcgi_help()
+
+    try:
+        import flup  # NOQA
+    except ImportError as e:
+        sys.stderr.write("ERROR: %s\n" % e)
+        sys.stderr.write("  Unable to load the flup package.  In order to run django\n")
+        sys.stderr.write("  as a FastCGI application, you will need to get flup from\n")
+        sys.stderr.write("  http://www.saddi.com/software/flup/   If you've already\n")
+        sys.stderr.write("  installed flup, then make sure you have it in your PYTHONPATH.\n")
+        return False
+
+    flup_module = 'server.' + options['protocol']
+
+    if options['method'] in ('prefork', 'fork'):
+        wsgi_opts = {
+            'maxSpare': int(options["maxspare"]),
+            'minSpare': int(options["minspare"]),
+            'maxChildren': int(options["maxchildren"]),
+            'maxRequests': int(options["maxrequests"]),
+        }
+        flup_module += '_fork'
+    elif options['method'] in ('thread', 'threaded'):
+        wsgi_opts = {
+            'maxSpare': int(options["maxspare"]),
+            'minSpare': int(options["minspare"]),
+            'maxThreads': int(options["maxchildren"]),
+        }
+    else:
+        return fastcgi_help("ERROR: Implementation must be one of prefork or "
+                            "thread.")
+
+    wsgi_opts['debug'] = options['debug'] is not None
+
+    try:
+        module = importlib.import_module('.%s' % flup_module, 'flup')
+        WSGIServer = module.WSGIServer
+    except Exception:
+        print("Can't import flup." + flup_module)
+        return False
+
+    # Prep up and go
+    from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application
+
+    if options["host"] and options["port"] and not options["socket"]:
+        wsgi_opts['bindAddress'] = (options["host"], int(options["port"]))
+    elif options["socket"] and not options["host"] and not options["port"]:
+        wsgi_opts['bindAddress'] = options["socket"]
+    elif not options["socket"] and not options["host"] and not options["port"]:
+        wsgi_opts['bindAddress'] = None
+    else:
+        return fastcgi_help("Invalid combination of host, port, socket.")
+
+    if options["daemonize"] is None:
+        # Default to daemonizing if we're running on a socket/named pipe.
+        daemonize = (wsgi_opts['bindAddress'] is not None)
+    else:
+        if options["daemonize"].lower() in ('true', 'yes', 't'):
+            daemonize = True
+        elif options["daemonize"].lower() in ('false', 'no', 'f'):
+            daemonize = False
+        else:
+            return fastcgi_help("ERROR: Invalid option for daemonize "
+                                "parameter.")
+
+    daemon_kwargs = {}
+    if options['outlog']:
+        daemon_kwargs['out_log'] = options['outlog']
+    if options['errlog']:
+        daemon_kwargs['err_log'] = options['errlog']
+    if options['umask']:
+        daemon_kwargs['umask'] = int(options['umask'], 8)
+
+    if daemonize:
+        from django.utils.daemonize import become_daemon
+        become_daemon(our_home_dir=options["workdir"], **daemon_kwargs)
+
+    if options["pidfile"]:
+        with open(options["pidfile"], "w") as fp:
+            fp.write("%d\n" % os.getpid())
+
+    WSGIServer(get_internal_wsgi_application(), **wsgi_opts).run()
+
+if __name__ == '__main__':
+    runfastcgi(sys.argv[1:])
diff --git a/django/utils/daemonize.py b/django/utils/daemonize.py
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..76f4d5d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/django/utils/daemonize.py
@@ -0,0 +1,62 @@
+import os
+import sys
+
+from . import six
+
+buffering = int(six.PY3)        # No unbuffered text I/O on Python 3 (#20815).
+
+if os.name == 'posix':
+    def become_daemon(our_home_dir='.', out_log='/dev/null',
+                      err_log='/dev/null', umask=0o022):
+        "Robustly turn into a UNIX daemon, running in our_home_dir."
+        # First fork
+        try:
+            if os.fork() > 0:
+                sys.exit(0)     # kill off parent
+        except OSError as e:
+            sys.stderr.write("fork #1 failed: (%d) %s\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
+            sys.exit(1)
+        os.setsid()
+        os.chdir(our_home_dir)
+        os.umask(umask)
+
+        # Second fork
+        try:
+            if os.fork() > 0:
+                os._exit(0)
+        except OSError as e:
+            sys.stderr.write("fork #2 failed: (%d) %s\n" % (e.errno, e.strerror))
+            os._exit(1)
+
+        si = open('/dev/null', 'r')
+        so = open(out_log, 'a+', buffering)
+        se = open(err_log, 'a+', buffering)
+        os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
+        os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
+        os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
+        # Set custom file descriptors so that they get proper buffering.
+        sys.stdout, sys.stderr = so, se
+else:
+    def become_daemon(our_home_dir='.', out_log=None, err_log=None, umask=0o022):
+        """
+        If we're not running under a POSIX system, just simulate the daemon
+        mode by doing redirections and directory changing.
+        """
+        os.chdir(our_home_dir)
+        os.umask(umask)
+        sys.stdin.close()
+        sys.stdout.close()
+        sys.stderr.close()
+        if err_log:
+            sys.stderr = open(err_log, 'a', buffering)
+        else:
+            sys.stderr = NullDevice()
+        if out_log:
+            sys.stdout = open(out_log, 'a', buffering)
+        else:
+            sys.stdout = NullDevice()
+
+    class NullDevice:
+        "A writeable object that writes to nowhere -- like /dev/null."
+        def write(self, s):
+            pass

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps are you'll need to have the VPS hosting, http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting, you won't be able to install Django on their normal hosting platform unless they have already done it for you.

Once you have a VPS set up, you'll have SSH credentials to login to the Linux host. (you should use PuTTY for this on Windows). Once you get SSH'd into the server, you can follow the instructions in the Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/install/) to install Django. (and it's dependencies)

Developing Django apps on Windows can be done, but is more difficult than developing on a linux host. That's an opinion.

Comment: As of 30.9.21 you do not need any specific account to host Django on Hostgator though you do need, as the first answer details, to apply a patch, and to administer the site yourself since Hostgator expressly do not provide support or assistance for Django installs to CGI. 

As far as on a deciated/VPS platform goes, I am not contradicting your answer since I was simply saying that it IS possible to host Django on their basic plans, but that it might be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I have also contacted hostgator support team. They are claiming Django is not fully supported by shared Hosting of Hostgator. You will need to get a dedicated or VPS.